# JS library to draw tree on Google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Is there any JS library for creating, drawing and maintaining binary trees into Google map APIv3?

Comment: What do you mean by binary tree?

Comment: What I meant was, do you know any js library that creates tree from Polylines, like binary tree, branching from single node(marker), where adding marker to tree structure, as a node, would create branch(polyline) to that node and so on, building tree like that...